# Detecting on which frame there is audio presence on a video

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg

I have a few video files that corresponds to a tv zapping (one channel with sound, then a black screen without sound, then sound again with the new channel)

I already detect pretty much everything but I would like to know how long it takes for the audio to appear after the end of the black screen.

Basically I extract the audio from the video and giving the starting frame I would like to know at which frame there is some audio again.

Then using that I can easily calculate the time it took for the audio to appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `blackdetect` and `silencedetect` filters and correlate the results.

Example usage:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -filter:v blackdetect=d=0.1 -filter:a silencedetect=d=0.1 -f null /dev/null
```

where `0.1` is the minimum duration (positive floating point value in seconds).

Example output:

```
[blackdetect @ 0x35f65e0] black_start:0.0464444 black_end:0.566444 black_duration:0.52
[blackdetect @ 0x35f65e0] black_start:5.16644 black_end:5.32644 black_duration:0.16
[blackdetect @ 0x35f65e0] black_start:15.9264 black_end:16.1664 black_duration:0.24
[blackdetect @ 0x35f65e0] black_start:33.4464 black_end:33.6064 black_duration:0.16
[blackdetect @ 0x35f65e0] black_start:63.9664 black_end:64.7664 black_duration:0.8
[silencedetect @ 0x35f8700] silence_start: 67.0521
[silencedetect @ 0x35f8700] silence_end: 67.9184 | silence_duration: 0.866236
```

Comment: This works really well for the black screen, sadly my video files has a lot of parasite noise and I can't seem to find a way to set a tolerance that works with the silence filter. 

Here is the video link if you want to try it : http://192.3.196.37/owncloud/index.php/s/jOmFRlmvPfAojyZ

Comment: @drov you could use a noise-gate before the silence detection. Check the [filters page](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html). If I remember correctly `agate` or `compand` might help.

Comment: agate seems like what I need but I can't find any example on how to use it. could you give me ant hints on that ? Thanks

Comment: @drov According [to this answer](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16974/how-does-the-agate-filter-in-ffmpeg-work) you can experiment with the [Calf Gate plugin](http://calf-studio-gear.org/) - it's under Dynamics - and use the resulting values for `agate`.